# Shortest paths on huge graphs: Neo4J or OrientDB?

Tags: distributed-databases, neo4j, graph, orientdb

Kia Ora,

I have a program that very frequently requires finding the fastest path (both the node sequence and total cost/length) on graphs containing ~50k nodes. Per run, I require on the order of millions of shortest path requests. I have just finished an OrientDB implementation which has significantly improved the compute time over my initial, non-graphDB attempt (which simply crashed). To perform testing, I am running the server locally on a series of distributed machines.

However, in theory, would Neo4J, or another such platform, be faster again? What gains could I expect to receive? Could I host this process online, for example?

Ngā mihi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for speed in a large number of requests, maybe you can try [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com). It's an in memory graph database which already has all your data stored to RAM, giving you an advantage since you don't need to load all your data to the disk. In general, 50K of nodes is not a large graph, and various databases have implemented their traversal algorithms directly into the core of the database.

Are you looking for the Dijkstra's shortest path, or fastest path which is defined by the number of hops?

Comment: Hello! I did not expect to get a response to this after so long - particularly on the day I return to working on this problem!

My current approach is to store the shortest path data (both the node path and distance, by Dijkstra's) in text files, loading that into memory when needed (very frequently). It's not perfect, but it works. I would love a more efficient method - I shall check out Memgraph, thank you!

Comment: I'd like to hear more about your ingestion practices. What is the format of the files? Is the data contained in text files the actual nodes the edges that need to be loaded and then on the graph you're running the algorithms to check for shortest paths?
Or you have actual shortest paths in the text files?

Comment: Thorough! In a single text file, I store i) all arc information (`a` --> `b` of cost `l`), ii) for each node `a`, the prior node `c` on the fastest path before reaching node `b`, and iii) for each node `a`, the cost `L` of the fastest path from `a` to `b`. 

This is stored in matrix form in a text file, which is loaded into Java as a custom graph. Many (many) operations are performed (i.e. we access the matrix, or use the 'prior' node information to construct the shortest path) on it before we move to load the next graph. We do not calculate Dijkstra's in Java - it's all been done for us.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that having a graph database with built in path algorithms should be quite faster than using OrientDB and Java. Not to say that Java is not that fast, but let's dissect into parts :)

Data representation: OrientDB is a relational database, right? By using a graph database, you'll be able to initially load your graph and save the ingestion part of building the in memory representation of accessing all the nodes and edges.

Compute time: since path algorithms like the shortest path are all built in, and most databases are written in C++, the speed should be considerate

Comment: 3rd, why I mentioned Memgraph, all your graph is already loaded in memory, so it should help :) now it's up to benchmarking and read efficiency vs. your implementation or tool you are using, so definitely give it a try and see if its good enough :D

Comment: I'm assuming you're using distributed machines to offload the servers based on the number of requests that are coming for the shortest path?

Comment: I certainly agree that it would be more efficient to do this all in a graph database. The text file containing the information I reference above for a graph containing ~13k nodes is over 2Gb - it's only exponential from there. To continue my research, I need to step onto a graph database. I simply need to learn how to do so. Currently, I don't really need to distribute the process, as requests for the shortest path are just accessing information stored in memory. I could distribute the construction of the shortest path (using the 'prior' node), maybe, but it seems unnecessary.